# gsutil iam ch command using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-python, gcloud-python

I am trying to use python to do the same functionality as this command:

gsutil iam ch group:group_name@gmail.com:objectAdmin gs://bucket_name

I am trying to give an objectAdmin role to a group using python. The above command works well in cloud powershell, but could not do it in python yet

I have tried to do this by replacing the "members": {member} with "groups": {group_name} in this add_bucket_iam_member function here:

```
def add_bucket_iam_member(bucket_name, role, member):
"""Add a new member to an IAM Policy"""
   # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
   # role = "IAM role, e.g., roles/storage.objectViewer"
   # member = "IAM identity, e.g., user: name@example.com"

   storage_client = storage.Client()
   bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

   policy = bucket.get_iam_policy(requested_policy_version=3)

   #policy.bindings.append({"role": role, "members": {member}})
   policy.bindings.append({"role": role, "groups": {group_name}})

   bucket.set_iam_policy(policy)

   print("Added {} with role {} to {}.".format(member, role, bucket_name))
```

It doesn't give an error but did not work either, after finishing it, and after getting policy dict again, it removes the group permission that I have sat. (meanwhile, it works fine with members)

I have also tried:

os.system("gsutil iam ch group:group_name@gmail.com:objectAdmin gs://bucket_name")

and

subprocess.run("gsutil iam ch group:group_name@gmail.com:objectAdmin gs://bucket_name", shell=True)
but did not work yet too.

Any help?

Comment: Eye-balling (!) your code, it looks correct (I'll need to try running it). I'm pleased to see you use Google's libraries rather than subprocess. How are you running it (locally?)? How are you authenticating it?

Comment: Notice the **group:** prefix added to the member ID in @DazWilin answer.

Comment: If you continue to have problems, show the old and new policy JSON in your question (redact some information).

Comment: @DazWilkin , I am using google-cloud-sdk and I have authenticated it correctly, as follows:     

1- after installation, used gcloud init command to initialize my account on the local dir.

2. generate a key from your SA
in python: 
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = <key_dir>
creds, project = google.auth.default()

3. cloud_storage_client = storage.Client(project=project, credentials=creds)

4. now your client is accessing your cloud project service from the local dir

    The needed libraries:
    import google.auth
    from google.cloud import storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your `policy.bindings.append` is incorrect.

You want what you originally had:

```py
role = "roles/storage.objectViewer"

group = "some@googlegroups.com"

member = f"group:{group}"

policy.bindings.append({
  "role": role,
  "members": {
    member,
  }
})
```

Full example:

```py
from os import getenv
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = getenv("BUCKET")
group = getenv("GROUP")
role = "roles/storage.objectViewer"

member = f"group:{group}"

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

policy = bucket.get_iam_policy(requested_policy_version=3)


policy.bindings.append({
    "role": role, 
    "members": {
        member,
    }
})
bucket.set_iam_policy(policy)

print("Added {} with role {} to {}.".format(member, role, bucket_name))
```

And:

```sh
PROJECT="[[YOUR-PROJECT]]"
ACCOUNT="[[YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT]]"
BUCKET="[[YOUR-BUCKET]]"
GROUP="[[YOUR-GROUP-EMAIL]]"

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/storage.admin

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json
export GROUP
export BUCKET

python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-storage
python3 main.py
```

Yields:

```
Added group:${GROUP} with role roles/storage.objectViewer to ${BUCKET}.
```

And:

```sh
FILTER=".bindings[]|select(.members|index(\"group:${GROUP}\")).role"

gsutil iam get gs://${BUCKET} \
| jq -r "${FILTER}"
```

Yields:

```
roles/storage.objectViewer
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It has solved it. Thanks for the great effort. It would be really appreciated if you could send me the source that states the correct syntax for adding a group since I have surfed lots of resources but did not get it well till your answer.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that it helped. Here's a very good [overview](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) of Google IAM. In the [IAM Policy](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#cloud-iam-policy) section it describes how to create a binding from a `role` and a `member` and summarizes the types of member.